# Unmarshalling XMLs generated from two XSDs

Tags: xsd, jaxb2

Here are two xsd definitions, both of them are almost 90% similar.Below are the skeleton of the first xsd:

```
XSD1 :

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="apf2doc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="request"/>
                <xs:element ref="account"/>
                <xs:element ref="financial_transaction"/>
                <xs:element ref="event_data" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And second xsd is:

```
XSD2:

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="apf2doc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="request"/>
                <xs:element ref="account"/>
                <xs:element ref="message"/>
                <xs:element ref="event_data" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now these two xsds generate two sets of classes in two different packages. I am using JAXB to unmarshall the xmls received. The xmls are generated from these two xsds.

While creating a JAXB context it throws me error because most of the classes cause conflict I believe.

Here is the error trace:

```
The element name {}userid has more than one mapping. This problem is related to the     following location: 
at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement   
generated.order.ObjectFactory.createUserid(java.lang.String) at   
generated.order.ObjectFactory this problem is related to the following location:
at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement   
generated.usage.ObjectFactory.createUserid(java.lang.String) at 
generated.usage.ObjectFactory
```

It would be great if someone can suggest me any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is old, but [the solution I posted in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71072922/2516673) might be of help for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Since your 2 XML schemas have global elements with the same name and namespace you won't be able to create a single `JAXBContext` on both models.  You can do one of the following:

1. Create a separate `JAXBContext` for each model.
2. Use namespaces to differentiate the 2 XML schemas.

Comment: Hi, Thank for the answer.  I believe I have to go the first war, creating separate JAXBContext because I cannot change the namespaces, its a third party thing here. :(